# listview must not be null

Tags: android, kotlin

I am a beginner at programming. I have an error message when I start my app and do not know what to do with the code. Can someone help me please.

Here is my code:

**Activity :**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val items = ArrayList<String>()
        items.add("Test1")
        items.add("Test2")
        items.add("Test3")

        listview1.adapter = Adapter1(this, items)

        val transaction1 = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragment1Button1.setOnClickListener{

            transaction1.replace(R.id.fragment1Platz,Fragment1())
            transaction1.commit()
        }

    }
}
```

**Fragment :**

```
class Fragment1 : Fragment() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false)
    }


}
```

**Adapter:**

```
class Adapter1 (context : Context, items : ArrayList<String>) : BaseAdapter() {


    private val context: Context = context
    private val items: ArrayList<String> = items


    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

        val listeneintrag = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter1_layout,parent, false)

        listeneintrag.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.adapter_textfeld1).text = items.get(position)

        return listeneintrag
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): String {
        return items.get(position)
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }
}
```

**Error stacktrace:**

> 2020-02-01 13:37:17.972 10729-10729/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main Process: strauss2002.yannick.fragmentetest, PID: 10729
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{strauss2002.yannick.fragmentetest/strauss2002.yannick.fragmentetest.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: listview1 must not be null at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) Caused
>   by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: listview1 must not be null at
>   strauss2002.yannick.fragmentetest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:29)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009) at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Here is my updated Main Activity:

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val listview1=findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listview1)

    val items = ArrayList<String>()
    items.add("Test1")
    items.add("Test2")
    items.add("Test3")

    listview1.adapter = Adapter1(this, items)

    val transaction1 = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    fragment1Button1.setOnClickListener{

        transaction1.replace(R.id.fragment1Platz,Fragment1())
        transaction1.commit()
    }

}
```

}

And here is the new error message:
2020-02-02 11:15:15.935 12764-12764/strauss2002.yannick.fragmentetest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: straus
s2002.yannick.fragmentetest, PID: 12764
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{strauss2002.yannick.fragmentetest/strauss2002.yannick.fragmentetest.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: listview1 must not be null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: listview1 must not be null
        at strauss2002.yannick.fragmentetest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:28)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Here is the xml of the activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment1Platz"
    android:layout_width="410dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

</FrameLayout>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/fragment1Button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:text="Öffne Fragment 1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.529"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the xml of the fragment_fragment1:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".Fragment1">

 <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="322dp"/>

 </FrameLayout>
```

Here is the xml of the adapter1_layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/adapter_textfeld1"
    android:layout_width="137dp"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please, add your a XML file with list view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't call `findViewById` for `listview1`.
Add `listview1=findViewById(R.id.yourListViewIdInXml);` just after `setContentView` method of `oncreate`

Or if you are using kotlin synthetic then make sure that `listview1` resides in `activity_main.xml` file

**Update**

The problem persists because you are calling `findViewById` on an id(listview1) which is not available in `activity_main.xml`. Note that in case of activities,   when you call `findViewById` it searches id in the layout file which is passed in `setContentView` method, that is `activity_main.xml` in your case. So when you called `findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listview1)` it searches listview1 in activity_main.xml, but as we know that there is no view available in activity_main.xml which has id=listview1, so findViewById simply returns null and that's why you are getting this error. So to get rid of this exception change:

```
val listview1=findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listview1)
```

to this:

```
val listview1=findViewById<ListView>(R.id.kontaktliste)
```

Comment: i don't think in kotlin you need to call `findViewById`

Comment: Now it's quite clear to understand for android developers

Comment: Thank you very much! The error is no longer displayed. However, the app still does not start and the following error message is displayed:2020-02-01 13:53:28.152 3156-11278/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 492)

Comment: @Suraj Vaishnav as soon as I clicked the "run-app" button and the app started. Then comes the message that the app has ended unexpectedly.

Comment: Have you added the entire onCreate code in question, because I don't see anything in `onCreate` that cause this problem.

Comment: Yes, I just checked it again

Comment: @Suraj Vaishnav I tried it again today and now I get an error message similar to the one at the beginning. It may be that I simply overlooked this error message after updating the main activity and maybe the message I wrote in my answer had nothing to do with the app crashing.

Comment: Okay, add your updated crash log and updated code in the question.

Comment: @YannickStrauss, please also add activity_main.xml code

Comment: @Suraj Vaishnav I added it

Comment: @Suraj Vaishnav I am very sorry. I accidentally copied the XML code from another program that I had just open into my question. The other XML code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I resolved just putting the `setContentView(activity_layout)` in the `onResume` method.

I don't know why this error hasn't occurred in other activities with a **listView**

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting Null Exception is that you are trying to access `listView1` before the fragment view is completely created which means `listView1` doesn't exist yet.

So you have to move that part of the code you have in your `MainActivity` to the `onCreateView` method of your fragment like so:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false)

        val items = ArrayList<String>()
        items.add("Test1")
        items.add("Test2")
        items.add("Test3")

        //THIS IS HOW YOU REFERENCE YOU VIEWS IN A FRAGMENT IN KOTLIN
        rootView.listview1.adapter = Adapter1(this, items)

        return rootView
    }
```

**And pay attention that in a fragment, you have to reference the views through the inflated rootView for your fragment.**